# How to Build FFMpeg as iOS Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build my own Player base on FFMpeg,

I succes to build FFMpeg as static library(*.a),

but its need to copy another header file to use,

I hope it can used like framework,

but even I add header file into framework (set as public)

My Demo App can not find .h file in FFMpeg.framework,

is there any suggestion or tutorial can help me to build it as real framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes because there is proper procedure to setup FFMPEG in project.

Please follow procedure in below link.

[Compile ffmpeg for iOS 6, support Simulator & armv7 & armv7s](http://witcheryne.iteye.com/blog/1734706)

1) First Download **[FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg)** From github.

2) Then just copy folder in your project directory.

3) Then Add it into your project with **Add file** option in xcode.

[image]

Note:- Below library must be added in your Project.

[image]

and don't forget to set **HEADER SEARCH PATH** in **Build Setting** option.

[image]

Try to compile.

You will find example for FFMPEG in below link,

1) [ffmpegc-demo](https://github.com/lvjian700/ffmpegc-demo)

2) [kxmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) (Best to use ffmpeg)

still you need to add ffmpeg in this demo also. else you will get error for headerfile missing or library missing or etc.

Comment: But this doesn't build it as a framework, as was asked? Just confirming

Comment: I think it not build as framework. if I add header search path in my demo app, it works fine, but what I want is not set include path in demo app, only set it in framework. is it possible?

Comment: yes @Devin sorry i thought you are facing problem for intigrate ffmpeg in project.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: How to build FFMPEG as an iOS Framework

Comment: Furthermore, unless your app is GPL licensed, this will violate the GPL.

Answer (score -1):

I've included several C libraries into an iOS project.  The way to do it, I think is to add the .a file to the Build Phases > Link Binary With Library, and drag your .a file there.  If you compiled ffmpeg from source, there should be a header file.  For your .h file, make sure you update the Library Search Path in Build Settings.

Also, if you are using the ffmpeg api's, maybe getting the libavcodec, libavformat, and libavscale libraries, as these are what the main ffmpeg program uses.

Comment: Yap, I can run ffmpeg fine, but if I want build it as framework, what should I do?

Comment: Why do you need to build it as a framework, if you can include it as a library just as easily?

Comment: Because I want to release it to my custom, so it must be a framework not source code, but I also do not want to release (framework+ include) , So I'm trying to build it together.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question: How to build FFMPEG as a Framwork