# How to integrate and use FFmpeg library in iOS with Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

I wanted to use FFMpeg library for video processing activities, from 2 days I m working on compiling and integrating this library with Xcode 8 and Swift. I tried following links but with no success. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

[FFMPEG integration on iphone/ ipad project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854190/ffmpeg-integration-on-iphone-ipad-project)

https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS

http://witcheryne.iteye.com/blog/1734706

[How to Build FFMpeg as iOS Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498103/how-to-build-ffmpeg-as-ios-framework)

https://github.com/ElfSundae/FFmpeg-iOS-build

https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie

Comment: Did you succeed in integrating ?If yes could you suggest how to integrate ffmpeg

Comment: No not yet, tried with AVFramework

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've tried [`mobile-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg), and it works (swift 4.2 - Xcode 10.1)
installation is very easy by cocoapods `pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl', '~> 4.2'`
you can use different binaries if you don't need all features, for example: `pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-min', '~> 4.2'`  [link](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg#2-using)

for using in swift you should [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header) `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` to your project and then import the library in that: `#import <mobileffmpeg/MobileFFmpeg.h>`

you can run a command like this in swift (converting mkv to mp4):

```swift
MobileFFmpeg.execute("-i video.mkv -codec copy video.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks Amir, for sharing this helpful link

Comment: HI @AmirKhorsandi, I need your help regarding same... I have to use this Library But dont know how can i accomplish this... Looking for your kind response. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ahtazaz can you explain a bit about your issue, you can also email me: khorsandi@me.com

Comment: I have just sent you an Email... please check... Thanks

Comment: Hi, @AmirKhorsandi I have installed MOBILE-Ffmpeg POD successfully, But the Issue is my Mac & Xcode Project gone wrong, mean very slow. Even I have clean Derived data but nothing works. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz I didn't have any issue with building in Xcode 10.1 - 10.2, (macOS 10.14) try using another mac

Comment: @Mr Ahtazaz   Do you have sample code for making duet video in iOS swift

Comment: @Amir Khorsandi - Sir do you have sample code swift file for making duet video

Comment: @DavenderVermaSoni No I don’t

Comment: @AmirKhorsandi. Sir did you perform task for making duet video in iOS swift

Comment: Hi @AmirKhorsandi is it possible to do a live stream to youtube using this library??

Comment: isnt ffmpeg by law impossible to integrate into ios apps because of lgpl lisence?