# How to convert .ogg file to .mp3/.caf to play in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

How to convert `.ogg` file to any supported `AVPlayer` file format so that I can play it in app. Now if I am uploading `.ogg` file the player shows its raw data so how to solve this?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804046/playing-an-ogg-stream-in-ios

Comment: i want no external lib added. Just want to convert .ogg to playable file format while player remains AVplayer . if i add other player my other scenario would crash . So just any algorithm to convert the data and compress it using swift language . @Prashant Tukadiya

Comment: any Supported Apple Format for Audio Which i can play using AVplayer would work

Comment: Sorry i am not aware about that. I found link that i share with you. :(

Comment: why you don't want to use any Library ? 
 here is one  https://github.com/lixing123/ExtAudioFileConverter

Comment: it does not convert .ogg file i think and any lib in swift ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)!

1. Import **mobile-FFmpeg** to your project. If you do not know how to import, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995875/how-to-integrate-and-use-ffmpeg-library-in-ios-with-xcode)
2. Use this `MobileFFmpeg.execute("-hide_banner -y -i [filename].ogg -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 [filename].mp3")` (I found this from the sample code of mobile-FFmpeg)
3. And you will get the converted mp3 file in your project.

*note: if your `.ogg` file is from the server, please download it first.