# How to use sunlubo/SwiftFFmpeg library in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, apple-m1, swift5

I am trying to use https://github.com/sunlubo/SwiftFFmpeg library in iOS to convert **mp4** file to **mpegts**. But I am getting below error when trying to add it using SPM:

[image]

& **No such module 'CFFmpeg'** error when trying to add the library manually as used in the Demo project(https://github.com/sunlubo/SwiftFFmpegDemo-iOS). Can anyone provide me the steps or example on how to use this library for iOS?

I am using a **M1 Macbook, Xcode 13, SwiftFFmpeg library version(1.0.5), Swift version(5.4)**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Mobile ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) cocoa pods like this:

```
pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl'
```

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312118/17927980 that's very helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @FredrikA. OK thanks, i add more information to my answer