# Add video overlay (with alpha component) on another video and export it

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

[image]I want to add overlay of video (with alpha component) on another video.
I need to play and export that as well. I have tried many things ,many tutorials but i am unable to do that.

I have also tried to use FFMPEG but its to complicated to understand in short time.so i tried to use wrapper but i am unable to run that on my device.
Is anyone have any idea how to do this ?
NOTE : I need to export that as well.

Comment: Please share image for overlay video position if possible.

Comment: try merging both videos. Use MutableComposition and divide both videos into seperate avasset and give same time duration for both videos and try to merge them.

Comment: @iOS_MIB i tried that but that was not working.

Comment: @PaulMarshal i will add image soon.

Comment: Check out this links it may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515955/overlay-two-videos-with-avfoundation
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-overlap-multiple-videos

Comment: @iOS_MIB i have gone through these link before but they are not working. Note my overlay video will be transparent.

Comment: @PaulMarshal  I have added image. Please check.

Comment: @iOS_MIB please check.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your video has been setup right to be transparent you can add the AVPlayerLayer over the other video and set this overlay video layer compositing filter to screenBlendMode.This is working for me on a current project.

```
overlayVideoLayer.compositingFilter = "screenBlendMode"
```

Comment: I need to export that as well. do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: provide your code to record currently and I will edit to show you

Answer (score 0):

I have try with using ffmpeg and its working

**Command to Overlay**

> ffmpeg -y -i /videoloc/video.3gp -i /overlaylocation/Overlay.png
>   -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v] -preset ultrafast -map [v] -map 0:a? -ac 2
>   /savevideolocation/file_20180427_125453.mp4

Comment: bro i know how to do this with commands but my problem is how to make FFMPEG work in iOS ? I tried using the FFMPEG wrapper for ios but that was not working . Then i tried to understand on my own but that's too complicated.

Comment: I have use this for the android `https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java`

Comment: yes this library is awesome but i have't found its iOS alternative.

Comment: yes this is a way to build complied libraries but i don't how to use them.Like the class and their usage is very complicated. It's very difficult to learn that in short span of time.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498103/how-to-build-ffmpeg-as-ios-framework